# Status Bar color doesn't change

Tags: android, android-theme, android-notification-bar, android-statusbar

I started an default Navigation Drawer Project in Android Studio.
After that i added a second activity. But in the layout of this second activity the status bar is white although it has the same theme like the automatically created layout where the `colorPrimaryDark` attribute works fine.

I played around a bit and figured out that a newly created theme `CustomTheme` which got the same items as `AppTheme` works great.

So using `android:theme="@style/CustomTheme.NoActionBar"` works but `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` doesn't. 
Changing the default application theme has no effect.

This is my `styles.xml`

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#3fff04</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>



<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ff0404</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

So, can you maybe explain me this little thing?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="APPActionBar" parent="@style/AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/action_bar_clr</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/menu_bg</item>
</style>
```

Your AndroidManifest.file 
add theme

```
 android:theme="@style/APPActionBar"
```

use same style as value-11 and value-14 folder